# disable mysite for a site collection (not for the whole farm or web app)

Tags: sharepoint

How to disable mysite for a particular site collection (SP 2007)? (disabling personal site through ssp affects all the site collections within that web application)

Answer (score 1):

Will changing the [Site Collections Master](http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/Blogs/GetThePoint/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=386) page to hide the links be the correct solution for you?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want personal sites, you should create a new ssp, new web application, and move the site collection there. Then disable my sites on it.